# Merging and adding two column vectors in a specific way in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have two column vectors "b" and "c"

```
b = [0;1;0;1;1;3;1;2;0;1]
c = [0.25; 0.21; 0.33; 0.22;0.24]
```

I need the output vector

```
output = [0; 0.25; 0.25; 0.46; 0.79;0.79; 1.01; 1.01; 1.01; 1.25]
```

Whenever there is 0 or any number (except 1) in index position 1 of b, it will assign 0  to output vector.

Whenever it finds the number 1  for the first time in b (in our case at 2nd index of b), it  will take 0.25 from c and assign to the output vector.

It will retain the same number in other index positions of output vector until there is zero or any number (except 1) in b, and whenever it finds the 1 in b, it will take second index of c and will add like  `(0.25+0.21 = 0.46)`.

Again it found the 1 at index position 5 of b, so it will take 3rd index element of  c and add like `(0.46+0.33)`. The process continues.
The size of the b and output vector are same...

Also, the number of 1s in b are equal to the  number of elements in c

Also, this is just an example, the actual size of the column vector "b'' will be like 400x1. So the suggested answer using loop indexing will be good enough.

Comment: There are several things that are hard to understand, like what you mean by “assign zero to the output vector”, and the scheme involving 1s and 0.25s. More importantly, where is your code? What have you written, and in what way is it not working? It would be better for you as a programmer, and easier for us to help, if you try to write this algorithm and ask for help when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this logic as follows in a loop, see the comments for details:

```
% Define inputs
b = [0;1;0;1;1;3;1;2;0;1];
c = [0.25; 0.21; 0.33; 0.22;0.24];

% Create helper arrays
output = zeros(size(b)); % Output defaults to [0, 0, ...]
cSum = cumsum(c);        % Cumulative sum of "c"
cIdx = 0;                % Current index in "cSum" for output
% Loop over the elements in "b"
for ii = 1:numel(b)
    if b(ii) == 1
        % If b(ii)=1 then we want to move to the next element in "cSum"
        cIdx = cIdx + 1;        
    end
    if cIdx > 0
        % If there has been at least one "1" in b so far then the output
        % should be taken from "cSum"
        output(ii) = cSum(cIdx);
    end
end
```

Alternatively, you could do this without a loop, but with the same underlying logic. Using `cumsum(b==1)` gives you the index for which element of `c` you want to use for the output. **This gives the same result:**

```
bIdx = cumsum(b==1)+1;
cSum = [0; cumsum(c)];
output = cSum(bIdx);
```

In your example, these both gives this as desired:

```
output = [0; 0.25; 0.25; 0.46; 0.79;0.79; 1.01; 1.01; 1.01; 1.25]
```

Both of these assume the number of `1`s in `b` is less than or equal to the number of elements in `c`, or they will error.